# unable to resolve host address ‘jellyfish.list’ - OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I tried to download the OpenVPN based on the article https://openvpn.net/cloud-docs/openvpn-3-client-for-linux/

In the 5th step, I've added $DISTRO = jammy jellyfish:
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos/openvpn3-jammy jellyfish.list

but I got the following

```
--2022-08-20 11:13:37--  https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos/openvpn3-jammy
Resolving swupdate.openvpn.net (swupdate.openvpn.net)... 104.18.110.96, 104.18.109.96
Connecting to swupdate.openvpn.net (swupdate.openvpn.net)|104.18.110.96|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2022-08-20 11:13:37 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2022-08-20 11:13:37--  http://jellyfish.list/
Resolving jellyfish.list (jellyfish.list)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘jellyfish.list’
```

Comment: Use `jammy` instead of `jammy jellyfish`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check $DISTRO using `lsb_release -a` :

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

so the $DISTRO should using Codename `jammy` like this :

```
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos/openvpn3-jammy.list
```

Finally you can Update and Upgrade your system.